# No product updates in Visual Studio 2017 15.2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 15.2 and I see no update to 15.3. Why is that? What's the right way to upgrade to 15.3?

**Edit:**

On my Dev PC there is no prompt to upgrade to 15.3, I'm stuck on 15.2:

[image]

On my Build Server I did get the option:

[image]

Now I have different versions of the software running in an Enterprise. How do I upgrade Visual Studio on my Dev PC? As pictured I am using the latest installer.

Comment: Inside VS 2017, I did not see any update notifications but when I run VS Installer, I was able to "Update" to 15.3

Comment: It is rolling out gradually. If you do want to upgrade now, download the 15.3 installer and run it.

Comment: @LexLi *rolling out gradually*, that is so silly. I have a Build Server with 15.3 and running the installer on my Dev PC wont detect the upgrade - so I'm stuck with 15.2. Its bad practice to run different software versions in an organisation. Where is [the download](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) the 15.3 installer? Even the https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/ 15.3 is vs_enterprise__231868156.1487043913 and that doesnt upgrade it!

Comment: @JeremyThompson if you scroll down the comments, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/08/14/visual-studio-2017-version-15-3-released/ you will soon see the answers from Microsoft employees. Sticking to 15.2 is nothing bad for the period, as Microsoft in fact just rolled out 15.3.1 to address immediate issues (and that's also why they roll out 15.3 gradually). If you are running an organization with many machines, you probably should be conservative and leave enough buffer time before bringing in an update like 15.3.

Comment: just press Modify and run installer

Comment: @Alexan it doesn't work that way, as I wrote *you get prompted to upgrade*, you **do not** click Modify to upgrade. Modify only allows you to *modify* the installation.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, yes, I know, but it worked for me one time. Update failed, I didn't get other prompt for update, I pressed modified, but changed nothing and update installed. Anyway it's way to try.

Comment: Oh this is just making ^&$%&^%'ing furious!!! From the MSDN 15.3 release article. *We definitely need a way to get back to 15.2. As it is today, 15.3 is completely broken. So broken, my team can’t continue using it. We NEED a way to get back to 15.2.* **and** *+1 Microsoft for downgrade path!!!*- common Microsoft...

Comment: Maybe that could help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4015967/troubleshooting-visual-studio-2017-installation-and-upgrade-failures (ps: there's a new version of VS installer from aug 22, maybe this will fix your setup magically ... )

Comment: As always cheers @Simon, can you please add that as an answer. Given 15.3.1 is only days after 15.3 you are probably going to be right.

Comment: right now we have 15.3.2

Answer (score 5):

It turns out waiting (patiently :-)) for the next version of the Visual Studio Installer seems to have fixed the problems.

Also, Microsoft has a troubleshooting page available here: [Troubleshooting Visual Studio 2017 installation and upgrade failures](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4015967/troubleshooting-visual-studio-2017-installation-and-upgrade-failures). I will quote the most important (a.k.a not obvious) parts for future reference:

> 1) Try to delete Visual Studio Installer data to remove corrupted
>   files:
>
> The Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper is a minimal light-weight
>   executable that installs the rest of the Visual Studio Installer.
>   Deleting Visual Studio Installer files and then rerunning the
>   bootstrapper might solve some upgrade failures. To do this, follow
>   these steps:
>
> - Close the Visual Studio Installer.
> - Delete the Visual Studio Installer packages and MDA folders to remove potentially corrupted downloaded files if they exist.
>     Typically, these directories are C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Visual
>     Studio\Packages.
> - Run the Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper. You may find the bootstrapper in your Downloads folder with a file name that follows a
>     vs_[Visual Studio edition]__*.exe pattern. If you don't find that
>     application, you can download the bootstrapper by going to the Visual
>     Studio downloads page and clicking download for your edition of Visual
>     Studio. Run this executable to reset your installation metadata.
> - Try to install or update Visual Studio again. [...]. Note This step will
>     reinstall Visual Studio Installer files and reset installation
>     metadata.
>
> 2) As a last resort, you can run InstallCleanup.exe.
>
> InstallCleanup.exe is a utility that's packaged with the Visual Studio
>   Installer, and it cleans up installation files. This isn't a full
>   reinstall. This utility deletes cache and instance data for Visual
>   Studio 2017 and deletes existing corrupt, partial and full instances
>   of Visual Studio 2017.
>
> - Close the Visual Studio Installer.
> - Open an administrator command prompt. To do this, follow these steps:
> - On the Start menu, click Run (Start + R).
> - Type cmd.
> - Right-click Command Prompt, and then choose Run as administrator.
> - Type the full path of the InstallCleanup.exe utility, and pass the following command line switch: -f. By default, the path of the utility
>     is as follows: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>     Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe`
> - Rerun the bootstrapper that's described in 1)
> - Try to install or update Visual Studio again.

Comment: Hi, I've had the installer left open for hours on my dev pc, on the Build Server I got the "Upgrade to 15.3, Y/N" MsgBox straight away. Is that what you meant by this *It turns out waiting (patiently :-)) for the next version of the Visual Studio Installer seems to have fixed the problems.* Sorry I'm not sure if you mean the installer (with the version in my screen shot) taking ages? After it's open? Thank you very much for the time & help you put into this answer.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - Hmmm. by patient, I meant "next version". In fact, there's almost always a VS installer update prior to a VS update. If the installer stays stale I would try the step described above, as I believe it should propose the update right away. Maybe a firewall/connectivity issue? Or a licence?

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks again. I wasn't able to mark this as correct; it is Sam's question. Appreciate your help, hence the bounty. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I run today from VS and I finally got:

[image]

(it took some minutes..)

Comment: I reversed the downvote - Lex Li was right 15.3.1 was delayed/withdrawn. I'll have to give the bounty to Simon for his thorough answer.